# How to disable local user lookup in amavis-new?

Tags: linux, ldap, email-server, amavis

I have amavis-new installed with iRedMail package.

Everything works OK for mails sent directly to existing user accounts. But I would like to use catch-all for domains and aliases.

The problem is that amavis LDAP queries does not take aliases and catch-all settings form OpenLDAP into account

I changed $enable_ldap to 0 but LDAP was still used, so I commented out LDAP query.
Unfortunately that didn't help.

How to completely disable checking of local users on the amavis level? I would like amavis to accept mail sent to any e-mail address. Postfix will do the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong blaming amavis for that problem.

After consulting with one of iRedMail developers I found that problem is with dovecot, not amavis

More information on this topic:
http://www.iredmail.org/forum/post18675.html